# 2008 Mercury Mariner 3.0L Cranks and acts like its going to start and stalls out, will run if I hold down throttle

Tags: stall, mercury, mariner

Just an order of events, I drove about 8 miles to a fast food place, placed my order and as I pulled away the car stalled when I let off the brake to move my foot to accelerator.  It runs if I hold the throttle down.  I don't hear any vacuum leaks and I'm unable to pull a code at the moment but just based on these symptoms, should I start with the IAC or MAF?  I'm kinda tight on cash at the moment and I'm just going attempt to throw parts at it, well just those 2 but of those should I start with the IAC as being the most likely suspect?

Comment: When you hold the throttle down, are you holding it to the floor, and if so, does it rev high? Once running and you let off the throttle, does it die again? As of your description, I don't think it's either the IAC or the MAF.

Comment: A common problem on these is the fuel pump.  It fails to generate enough pressure and the engine stalls.  You might check the fuel line pressure at the engine and see if it's in spec.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 I have to hold it down a bit initially to get it to start and then I can hold my foot on throttle and bring it down but if I let off completely it stalls.  It seems to run fine once it's moving, I did just kinda hold the idle up and as bad as it is just jammed it into drive but I was able to drive home although all highway it ran fine just when I got off the exit I had to kinda hold the brake and keep the idle above like 800 or so.

Comment: @jwh20 I considered the fuel pump but it runs once I get it started, I even drove home after with no issues other than coming to a stop I had to hold the idle up with my foot on the brake to keep it from stalling.

Comment: I'd put a multimeter on the throttle position sensor (TPS) and see that it is operating correctly. If you have an OBDII reader which will show Live Data, you can see how it appears to the ECU. The '08 Mariner may/may not have a drive by wire setup. If it does, it could be your pedal which is at issue.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Is it the 2 end pins?  And what voltage should it read? Been a while since I've tinkered.  Thanks

Comment: In most cases with a TPS you want to check the sweep of the gauge. To do that, you unplug it and check resistance. I don't know what the resistance *should be*, but whatever the reading is, you want to make sure it is a continual, even sweep. If you see where resistance stops moving and jumps, or drops to zero then back again, you have dead spots. I don't know which pins it would be, so you might need to search to see which ones give readings. This is what I'd be checking for. It is a lot easier to check it through the ECU and Live Data if that means if available to you.

Comment: @Derek Regardless, I urge you to check the fuel pump.  I had exactly these symptoms and it turned out that the pump wasn't able to provide enough fuel when starting and the battery voltage was low due to cranking.  Once started it ran fine.

Comment: In addition to jwh20's suggestion to check fuel pressure, AutoZone and Advance Auto loan tools like a fuel pressure gauge. If your fuel rail has a fuel test valve, the same as tire valves, unscrew to (black?) plastic dust cap to reveal a Schrader valve and connect a working f/p gauge to measure pressure. It takes more time to explain how to do it than hooking it up and turning on ignition. Have spark plugs been replaced? Refrain from throwing parts at a problem when there are ways to test the iacv and maf sensor.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, got hung up at work today going to run to autozone and see if  they can lend me the test gauge  for fuel pressure and test parts out.  Will report back tomorrow.

Comment: I tested the fuel pump and everything else all checked out. Ended up being a fuse.